# Trying to register a package with bower - "EMALFORMED failed to read \path to file\bower.json" "Unexpected string"

Tags: package, bower, package-managers

I have never used bower before and I am trying to register a package with it. From everything I have read including similar problems on SO, I can't tell where I've gone wrong. The additional error details say "unexpected string".

Here is my bower.json file:

```
 {
    "name":"One-Nexus",
    "description":"A sensible and intuitive front end solution.",
    "version":"1.1.0",
    "keywords":[
       "css",
       "sass",
       "js",
       "responsive",
       "mobile-first",
       "front-end",
       "framework",
       "web",
       "development"
    ],
    "homepage":"http://www.onenexusproject.com/",
    "ignore":[
       "/assets/js/jquery.min.js",
       "/assets/js/modernizr.min.js",
       ".git",
       ".gitattributes",
       ".gitignore",
       "bower.json",
       "cheatsheet.html",
       "index.html",
       "README.md"
    ],
    "dependencies":{
       "jquery: >=1.10.0",
       "modernizr: >=2.8.3"
    }
 }
```

The most common reason for the problem I'm getting seems to be errors in the json. Initially, indeed there were, but I have since ran the code through an online validator and ensured the code is valid. The other common reason is the presence of BOM characters. I have tried minifying the code, and also saving it in plain old Notepad in both UTF-8 and ANSI, but nothing seems to work. Where have I gone wrong?

EDIT: I have now tried countless different variations of bower.json including only the bare minimum needed, I have tried saving the file in different text editors, I've tried saving with different encoding, I've tried writing the code from scratch, nothing is working - I'm still getting the same error of "Unexpected string". There are no solutions on Google or SO. I am baffled. Could I be overlooking something extremely obvious?

Here is an image showing the exact error, with what I believe to be the valid code on the left: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABljG.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enter code here`The value of the dependencies field is not valid. This should be a hash of package name to a semver compatible identifier or URL.
Using the following should fix the problem:

```
"dependencies":{
   "jquery": ">=1.10.0",
   "modernizr": ">=2.8.3"
}
```

**Update**

The `bower.json` in the master branch of https://github.com/esr360/One-Nexus is valid, however bower is using the one in the your latest version - the 1.1.0 tag - and this one is not valid (dependencies field, commas in wrong places).
Using the valid `bower.json` from the master branch in the 1.1.0 tag should solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for answering. In the midst of different variations I've tried for bower.json, I've tried versions without the dependencies section altogether, and I have even tried only the following:

    {
        "name":"One-Nexus"
    }

However, no matter what I do, no matter what combination of bower.json I try I constantly get the same error.

Comment: Here is an image with updated code using your suggestion, and the error: http://i.imgur.com/0087jTd.png

Comment: @EdmundReed see the update to my answer. the issue is with bower.json in the 1.1.0 tag which is not valid

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't tell you how long I've spent fretting over this, and to find out it was such a rookie mistake on my part is so annoying - but thanks you have really saved me here!